# MKMapview without cell/wifi connections not showing correctly on the device

Tags: ios, mkmapview, coordinates, cllocationmanager

```
 #define LOCATION_DISTANCE 80.4672
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     ....some computation
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 360.0*NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    });
     ..........some more computation
 }
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

  CLLocation *obj = [locations lastObject];
  if (obj.coordinate.latitude != 0 && obj.coordinate.longitude != 0 )
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currrentCoordinates ;
    currrentCoordinates.latitude = obj.coordinate.latitude;
    currrentCoordinates.longitude = obj.coordinate.longitude;
 if(obj.horizontalAccuracy>0 && obj.horizontalAccuracy<100){
            self.turnedOffLocationServices =YES;
                [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

        } .... more computation
  [self setUpMap:currrentCoordinates];
}
 - (void)setUpMap:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)currentCoordinates
{
      MKCoordinateRegion extentsRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentCoordinates, LOCATION_DISTANCE, LOCATION_DISTANCE);

MKMapView *mvMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 594, 360, 347)];
mvMap.delegate = self;
[mvMap setRegion:extentsRegion animated:YES];
mvMap.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
mvMap.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
//mvMap.showsUserLocation = YES;
NSLog(@"the current lat is %f", currentCoordinates.latitude);
NSLog(@"the current long val is %f", currentCoordinates.longitude);

[self.scrollView addSubview:mvMap];

ITMAnnotation *annotation = [[ITMAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:currentCoordinates addressDictionary:nil];
annotation.title = @"Drag to Move Pin";
annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"subtitle change at 314");

[mvMap addAnnotation:annotation];
self.tempMapView = mvMap;
}
```

So i have viewDidLoad that creates location manager. I use didUpdateLocations as I think it is supposed to. I call setUpMap method with that co-ordinates and i get a map at the bottom left corner of my ipad screen. 
My problems are:1)When in no-wifi/cell mode i don't get the accurate location. Its way off. But i put in the co-ordinates manually( have text fields which will take this co-ordinates) it works and shows the location. 
2)I added suppose 4 records in this no-wifi/no cell mode. I can add 3 fine with map showing( but again different location way off my current location). But on the 4th time(or later some time) when i visit the screen where map should show up is white. Does this make sense. IF you need more information please ask. Thanks.. Oh and all this is on the device NOT simulator. And its iOS6.

Comment: By "no-wifi/no cell mode" do you mean "airplane" mode? Is the cell chip turned off, or you're just out of reception?

Comment: @Craig. I mean i turn off wifi and cell on my device.  I am turning them off to simulate condition in no reception area mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell and the GPS are on the same chip so turning the cell off turns off the GPS too. If you just want to stop data transfers but still want GPS then you can turn off Mobile Data under Network settings. You'll still be able to make calls, but your device can't download anything (if you turn off wifi too).

Comment: So can you tell me when user is using an app that has MapView on it in a place where there is no WiFi/no cell connection, what will happen to the map view? If he is on an AirPlane,what then?Does the GPS work in either places?

Comment: The GPS works without a connection, because it is true GPS, it talks to the satellite. But if you turn off the cell chip (as in turn on "Airplane" mode) the GPS is turned off too. You can still see some map data if it has been cached but it won't get anymore (obviously, no data connection) but it can't work out you location. At that point it is up to the developer to do something. They can show errors, they can crash, they can wait until the GPS gets a signal.

Comment: The GPS will work on a plane, but it's called "airplane" mode because most airlines want to you turn all that stuff off while you're flying.

Comment: Ok.Got it.So on the device now, i turned on Airplane mode got to the screen where there is a MapView. I see white space in-place of MapView. So about the no wifi/no cell signal on a remote field on ground. Will the map pull the current location.?

Comment: The GPS works without a _data_ connection, because it is true GPS, it _listens_ to satellites, not cell towers. (Although when it an listen to cell towers/wifi it gets a fix quicker, look up AGPS)